# how to include Angstrom symbol and Greek letters in gnuplot?

Tags: gnuplot

I am using gnuplot and would like to get the symbol for "Angstrom" (`Å`, ISO encoding 305) and the Greek letter Delta (`Δ`, Symbol 104) in the plot. How can I combine the two encoding schemes when producing my output eps?

Answer (score 3):

For readability of your code, why not use UTF8?

```
set xlabel "{/Symbol D} Δ (Å)"
```

Gives in PDF terminal : 
[image: result]

with encoding to default but UTF8 as system wide locale:

```
gnuplot> show encoding

nominal character encoding is default
however LC_CTYPE in current locale is fr_FR.UTF-8
```

Answer (score 2):

You can see the characters in this example:

```
set terminal postscript eps color enhanced size 10cm,10cm
set output 'pic.eps'
set encoding iso_8859_1
set xlabel "{/Symbol=30 a}"
set ylabel "{/Symbol=30 b}" 
set label "Label {/Symbol \104}{\305} End" at 1.7,2.5 font "Times,30"
set title "TITLE {/Symbol=30 \104}{/Helvetica=30 \305} END"
set key off
plot "-" with lines
1 3
2 2
3 3
end
```

The syntax for a character is `{/`*fontname*`=`*size* `\`*code*`}` so for example we have `{/Symbol=30 \104}` for the delta, and `{/Helvetica=30 \305}` or just `{\305}` for Angstrom. Ensure you have `set encoding iso_8859_1` or similar to use the ISO Latin-1 encoding.
See *Enhanced text mode* in the gnuplot guide at [gnuplot.info](http://www.gnuplot.info).

[image]